# How to show only current section including all its subsections in beamer?

Tags: beamer

In beamer, how to show only the current section and all its subsections non-shaded in the TOC at the beginning of a section but all other sections and subsections shaded?

For example, in the following TOC only Section 1 and Subsections 1.1 and 1.2 should be in regular font (as highlighted in bold) on the first slide of Section 1 containing the `\tableofcontents` command and everything else should be shaded:

**Section 1**
**Subsection 1.1**
**Subsection 1.2**
Section 2
Subsection 2.1
Subsection 2.2
Section 3

Comment: Please add a small, but compilable test document.

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\AtBeginSection{
\begin{frame}
\tableofcontents[currentsection]
\end{frame}
}

\begin{document}

\section{1}
\subsection{1.1}
\subsection{1.2}
\section{2}
\subsection{2.1}
\subsection{2.2}
\section{3}


\begin{frame}
  abc
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```